# md-slider range for year (.0 to .11)

Tags: angularjs, slider, angular-material

. [image]

In the above image after 7.9 range is moving to 8, but i want it to slide to 7.10, 7.11 then 8.

How can we get md-slider range for year.

```
 <md-slider md-discrete class="md-primary m-t-30" step=".1" min="0" max="30" aria-label="rating" tabindex="6" name="serviceTenure" ng-model="job.serviceTenure"  ng-required='job.positionCriteria'>
    </md-slider>
```

Comment: Please post the code that you tried and also a fiddle if possible.

Comment: @PrerakSola update the question with code.